# Show multiple ads in middle of article post in blogger with shortcodes

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, adsense

I want to show ads on blogger posts using shortcodes. With the help of shortcode, I can add multiple ads like 4 to 5 ads in the blogger post. But I don't know how to do this.

Here **some methods are available on the internet** in which we can add **2 to 3 ads only**. This is the code

```js
<div expr:id='"adsmiddle1" + data:post.id'></div>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0">
<!-- Add here the code of your ad -->
</div>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<div expr:id='"adsmiddle2" + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj0=document.getElementById("adsmiddle1<data:post.id/>");
var obj1=document.getElementById("adsmiddle2<data:post.id/>");
var s=obj1.innerHTML;
var r=s.search(/\x3C!-- adsense --\x3E/igm);
if(r>0) {obj0.innerHTML=s.substr(0,r);obj1.innerHTML=s.substr(r+16);}
</script>
```

Using the above code we can add Adsense ads code only by 2 times in blogger post by this shortcodes `<!-- adsense -->`  but I want to modify it for multiple Adsense placement.

Comment: This is the blogger link where i want to show it https://haseebguider.blogspot.com/2022/04/adsense.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<b:loop values='data:widgets.AdSense' var='AdSense'>

  <data:AdSense.title/>
  <data:AdSense.type/>
  <data:AdSense.sectionId/>
  <data:AdSense.id/>

</b:loop>
```

source: https://www.thoughtco.com/add-adsense-to-blogger-1616427

Comment: what is this i dont understand?